# C++11 / C++03 and std::vector thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, stl

I am reading about thread safety of various stl containers from this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Thread_safety)
Now I came across this point which states for C++11 only

> Different elements in the same container can be modified concurrently
>   by different threads, except for the elements of `std::vector<bool>`
>   (for example, a vector of `std::future` objects can be receiving values
>   from multiple threads)

Does this mean if I have a method such as this which is being used by multiple 
threads simultaneously `(notice the method does not have any locks)`

```
void ChangeValue(int index , int value)
{
   someVector[index] = value;
}
```

Is the above method safe. My understanding is that it is safe for C++11 only.
However when I look at the other statement mentioned in the link

> All const member functions can be called concurrently by different
>   threads on the same container. In addition, the member functions
>   begin(), end(), rbegin(), rend(), front(), back(), data(), find(),
>   lower_bound(), upper_bound(), equal_range(), at(), and, except in
>   associative containers, operator[], behave as const for the purposes
>   of thread safety (that is, they can also be called concurrently by
>   different threads on the same container). More generally, the C++
>   standard library functions do not modify objects unless those objects
>   are accessible, directly or indirectly, via the function's non-const
>   arguments, including the this pointer.

I come to the conclusion that in C++03 the above method can be safely used as well.
Kindly let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: It is meaningless to ask whether something is thread-safe under C++03 - C++03 and earlier didn't have any concept of threads or thread safety.

Comment: `ChangeValue` is thread-safe (as defined by C++11 and later) as long as no two threads pass the same argument for `index`, or else calls passing the same argument are synchronized with each other by some means external to the function.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Igor. Could you put that as an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is meaningless to ask whether something is thread-safe under the C++03 standard - C++03 and earlier didn't have any concept of threads or thread safety.

`ChangeValue` is data race-free (as defined by C++11 and later) as long as no two threads pass the same argument for `index`, or else calls passing the same argument are synchronized with each other by some means external to the function.